# Force Close at addition/sum from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to addition the value of each field, stored in Firestore Document and sum a total of this.

Anyway, heres the code i used:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference userExercisesRef = rootRef.collection("Nicks");
DocumentReference DocRef = userExercisesRef.document("User");
CollectionReference ColRef = DocRef.collection("Wertung");
Query query = ColRef.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Bewertung", "0.5");
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            long count = 0;
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                long Wertung = document.getLong("Wertung");
                count = count + Wertung;
            }

            Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(count));
        }
    }
});
```

I'm gettin a force close with the fault code:

```
com.example.XXXXXXXXX/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.XXXXXXXXX, PID: 240XX
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Field 'Wertung' is not a java.lang.Number
```

I've tried with double and document.getDouble(), but same fault code here.

What am i doing wrong? How to solve this problem?

The Value is from 0.5 to 5.0 - its a Rating for the RatingBar. I would like to sum all Ratings and show the average sum in a RatingBar. The Ratings are saved as String in Firestore Document

Comment: The error is telling you that the Wertung field is not actually a long as your code is expecting.  We can't see the data in your database, so we don't know what it actually is.

Comment: Attach a debugger and check what type is "Wertung". If it is a string you can parse it.